# mydumper isn't generated replica metadata

Tags: mysql, mydumper

I'm running mydumper to generate a dump of a MySQL and the `metadata` file only contains:

```
$ cat metadata
Started dump at: 2023-08-13 17:30:00
Finished dump at: 2023-08-13 17:45:08
```

while on the document it says it should look like this:

```
Started dump at: 2011-05-05 13:57:17
SHOW MASTER STATUS:
Log: linuxjedi-laptop-bin.000001
Pos: 106

Finished dump at: 2011-05-05 13:57:17
```

My full command looks like this:

```
  mydumper \
    --host="$MYSQL_ADDRESS" \
    --user="$MYSQL_USERNAME" \
    --password="$MYSQL_PASSWORD" \
    --database="$MYSQL_DATABASE" \
    --port=3306 \
    --outputdir="$dump_dir" \
    --threads="$(nproc)" \
    --no-locks \
    --verbose=3 \
    --long-query-retries=1 \
    --build-empty-files \
    --rows=100000
```

Any ideas what am I missing?